# Is there any way to make a date object in 12 hour mode in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hii,

I have to make date time in 12hr mode i.e. 23 January 2010 1:30 PM in java script

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always use a wrapper on getHours() and convert to the 12 hr format.

```
Date.prototype.getHoursIn12HrMode = function() {
    var h = this.getHours();
    if(h == 0)
        return 12;
    return (h > 12) ? h - 12 : h;
}
```

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) is a nice library to use if more customizations are needed.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Date object will allow you to format the date in the format defined by the user's system - this may or may not include AM/PM (it may not be in English either). You can format it yourself, of course, using something like [this](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/formatting_time_using_javascript.php3). For complete control, use a [`strftime()`](http://hacks.bluesmoon.info/strftime/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Steven Levithan has published a JS script which implements all sorts of date-time masks.  It includes a 12-hour clock element.  [Find out more](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).